# Rule to measure maximum lines in a method in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

I am working with flutter project and new to dart programming. I need to validate the length of the method. For example, consider the following method.

```
void test(){
   //Need to validate the number of lines in this method
}
```

I need to know the **dart lint rule** to be used to restrict the length of the line in all the methods I am using in my project i.e for example the length of the **test** method need to be only 50 lines. Kindly suggest me a way to restrict the method length.

Thanks in advance,
Dharani.

Answer (score 1):

This is for characters of line https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#avoid-lines-longer-than-80-characters
It's very clear

> If you really find yourself wanting lines longer than 80 characters, our experience is that your code is likely too verbose and could be a little more compact. The main offender is usually VeryLongCamelCaseClassNames. Ask yourself, “Does each word in that type name tell me something critical or prevent a name collision?” If not, consider omitting it.
>
> Note that dartfmt does 99% of this for you, but the last 1% is you. It does not split long string literals to fit in 80 columns, so you have to do that manually.

They don't talk much about how many lines should be in the class, methods, ...
But, with this article, you should follow if you wanted: https://dzone.com/articles/rule-30-%E2%80%93-when-method-class-or

For specific:

> Methods should not have more than an average of 30 code lines (not counting line spaces and comments).